# Remove unsaved text in Emacs

Tags: undo

Is there a way to remove unsaved text and get back the latest saved state of a file in Emacs without using `undo`?

Like this:

```
| a - write some text to save
| b - save the file
| c - add some text to remove
| d - more text  to remove
| e - command/function to remove all text after b
```

Comment: Do you mean for the sequence to be `a-b-c-d-e` instead of `a-b-c-d-d`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I just edit it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `M-x revert-buffer`.  A buffer only [visits](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html) a file.  The `revert-buffer` function reloads the current buffer's source file from disk.  So long as the file hasn't changed since you last saved it, as might happen if another process writes to it, `revert-buffer` will restore the buffer to point `b`, removing all text inserted after `b`.

As a bonus, you don't need to type the whole thing.  Typing `M-x rev-b` is sufficient.

Comment: Well maybe I was daydreaming but am sure I saw something like `revert-buffer-region` while assigning a key binding  for `revert-buffer`- And I even read the description saying something like "*undo selected region in a buffer*". Now it just "disappeared".

Comment: Sometimes that's an indication that the function you saw was from a package that isn't currently loaded.

Comment: To quote the `undo` help: `In Transient Mark mode when the mark is active, only undo changes within
the current region.  Similarly, when not in Transient Mark mode, just C-u
as an argument limits undo to changes within the current region.`  Select a region of text and then do `C-u C-/` to undo *within the selection*.  Might that be what you read?

Comment: Just checked - this is not part of the Emacs tutorial.  Wonder if it should be.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Well, I don't know anymore what I saw but it was part of the suggested function by company. It's funny cause I stopped, read what it does in a small description on the modeline, But it was "gone" when I came back lol. Never Mind, will probably find it again. :)

Comment: If it was written to the minibuffer, then it should have been written to `*Messages*`.  If it happens again, check `C-h e`.   If it's something you've called (within the last 300 commands), you would also see it in `C-h l` (that's an 'ell').

Comment: ok, thanks. Will let you know if it happens again.